# Can zxing.net.mobile read small barcodes in xamarin android?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, zxing

In the last few days I have been trying to implement a barcode scanner in xamarin android and I found a lot of good examples for zxing.net.mobile so I made an app using that.

It is working fine for normal sized barcodes but with small barcodes it never works.

The barcodes I'm trying to read are approximately 1.5 cm long and 0.5 cm tall code 128 barcodes.

I tried with fragments, services and the default layout too, none of them seem to read these small barcodes.

I tried the offical zxing app from the app store and it can read them fine so probably I'm doing something wrong here.

I based my app on this question's accepted answer:
[How to create and implement a Android CustomOverlay for ZXing Scanner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57303386/how-to-create-and-implement-a-android-customoverlay-for-zxing-scanner)

Can someone point me in the right direction because at this point I'm out of ideas.

I have the initialization in the OnCreate in MainActivity:

```
Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(Application);
ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();
```

Here's the method I use to start scanning, it's in MainActivity:

```
private async void Scan()
{
    Forms.Init(this, Intent.Extras);
    var result = await DependencyService.Get<CameraService>().ScanAsync();
    if (result != null)
    {
         //This is a utility method I use in most of my apps to show a simple AlertDialog with title, message and an 'ok' button
         Util.Popup("Found barcode", result.Text + "\nType: " + result.BarcodeFormat, this);
    }
    else
    {
         Toast.MakeText(this, "No barcode found", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

Here's the service:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using ZXing.Mobile;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(test.CameraService))]
namespace test
{
    public class CameraService : Service
    {
        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public async Task<ZXing.Result> ScanAsync()
        {
            var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner
            {
                UseCustomOverlay = true,
            };

            var options = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions()
            {
                TryHarder = true,
                AutoRotate = false,
                UseFrontCameraIfAvailable = false,
                PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat>()
                {
                    ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_128
                },
                CameraResolutionSelector = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions.CameraResolutionSelectorDelegate(SelectLowestResolutionMatchingDisplayAspectRatio)
            };

            View scanView = LayoutInflater.From(Application.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.Scanner, null);
            ImageButton flashBtn = scanView.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.flashBtn);
            flashBtn.Click += delegate
            {
                scanner.ToggleTorch();
            };
            
            scanner.CustomOverlay = scanView;

            ZXing.Result scanResults = await scanner.Scan(this,options);
            return scanResults;
        }

        private CameraResolution SelectLowestResolutionMatchingDisplayAspectRatio(List<CameraResolution> availableResolutions)
        {
            CameraResolution result = null;
            //a tolerance of 0.1 should not be visible to the user
            double aspectTolerance = 0.1;
            var displayOrientationHeight = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Orientation == DisplayOrientation.Portrait ? DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height : DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width;
            var displayOrientationWidth = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Orientation == DisplayOrientation.Portrait ? DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width : DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height;
            //calculating our targetRatio
            var targetRatio = displayOrientationHeight / displayOrientationWidth;
            var targetHeight = displayOrientationHeight;
            var minDiff = double.MaxValue;
            //camera API lists all available resolutions from highest to lowest, perfect for us
            //making use of this sorting, following code runs some comparisons to select the lowest resolution that matches the screen aspect ratio and lies within tolerance
            //selecting the lowest makes Qr detection actual faster most of the time
            foreach (var r in availableResolutions.Where(r => Math.Abs(((double)r.Width / r.Height) - targetRatio) < aspectTolerance))
            {
                //slowly going down the list to the lowest matching solution with the correct aspect ratio
                if (Math.Abs(r.Height - targetHeight) < minDiff)
                    minDiff = Math.Abs(r.Height - targetHeight);
                result = r;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

And the last part Scanner.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:background="@color/SemiTransparent">
        <TextView
            android:text="Place the camera above the barcode."
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:id="@+id/topText"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:id="@+id/scanView"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="@color/SemiTransparent">
        <TextView
            android:text="Wait for automatic scanning."
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/bottomText"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/lamp_ON"
            android:id="@+id/flashBtn"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does your app work with a "normal" sized Code128?

Comment: @DavidChristopherReynolds Yes it works, it works on about 2 cm long and 1 cm tall barcodes and bigger ones.

Comment: I've used the zxing library before. I was gonna say use TryHarder set to true but you've already done that! Could you try setting a higher resolution in SelectLowestResolutionMatchingDisplayAspectRatio? Perhaps the resolution is too low. Also, does the camera seem to focus properly? I've had issues getting it to focus in the past.

Comment: @DavidChristopherReynolds I have tried many things including setting resolution to 1920x1080 which is the phone's max it can do. Yeah the focus works best from about 10-15 cm. Mostly it only has problems focusing when I move it closer than about 5-6 cm.